# executing SQL in Grails twice as slow as executing same SQL in work bench, any ideas why?

Tags: sql, performance, grails

I have a reporting application written in grails.   it fires SQL at a production back office database, and simply lists the resultant rows back to the user.

The bit which executes the sql is this:

```
class ReportService {
static transactional = false
def dataSource_target

def runReport(sql) {
     def rows = null
     def start
     def con

     start = System.currentTimeMillis()

     try {
         con = new Sql(dataSource_target)
         rows = con.rows(sql)
     } finally {         
        con.close()
     }

     def time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start

     def response = [rows: rows, time:time,]

     response
 }
```

When this runs, it takes say 60 seconds (60000 ms). If I run the exact same SQL using mysql work bench or similar, it comes back in 30 seconds.  Thats a big difference!

Typicically on 30 or so rows are returned, so there is not much network overhead.

Any ideas why grails should be to run the query and red the results?

Answer (score 1):

The `time` variable in your code measures the total of

1. time to create the connection
2. time to execute the query
3. time to destroy the connection

To more accurately measure just (2), change your code to

```
def runReport(sql) {
     def rows = null
     def time
     def con

     try {
         con = new Sql(dataSource_target)
         def start = System.currentTimeMillis()
         rows = con.rows(sql)
         time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start
     } finally {         
         con.close()
     }

     def response = [rows: rows, time:time,]
     response
}
```

Comment: Very interesting.I had assumed the time to create and destroy the connect (from a pool) would be negligible, not minutes, but Ill try your suggestion right away.

Comment: I measured both the total time (original listing) and the inner time (just the sql call). Both numbers are identical.  If i run via grails, the times for one particular report are 48 seconds.  If I run the same report via mysql work bench on the same server, the time is 30s.  For some reason, calling SQL via grails/hybernate is VERY slow